# Check lines A and count it until it changes to lines B javascript

Tags: javascript

I am sorry in advance if my title is somehow misleading and I am really sorry for my English if you wouldn't understand me, it's just not my native language!

I will try to explain as better as I can about what I try to achieve. I try to do this for past two entire days and I really need your help!

Let's say I have array with the following numbers:

2 4 6 8 10 1 3 5 2 4

I am trying to count how many even and odd numbers are here in a row, and when even/odd changes - count it again. So my answer from the array above should be:

5 (5 even numbers in a row) 3 (3 odd lines in a row) (2 even lines in a row)

Also when the counting isn't stopped it should post `"<br>"` instead of counted evens/odds, so it could show me results one time near to each line.

Check this example image:
[image]

I have this script which is counting, but it has a few issues: when number is even, it shows counting twice. Next, I can't figure it out how to add `<br>` to these lines where counting and add result only at the last line of counting. Also my counting result should be at the top, so the script should count from the end as I guess, and when I try i-- it starts the infinite loop...

```
var digits = ["2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4"]

var evenCount=1, oddCount=1;

for(var i =0; i < digits.length; i++){

if(digits[i] % 2 ==0){

     var oddCount=1;

       $("#res").append(evenCount + " (l) <br>");
      evenCount++;
     }
    else
    var evenCount=1;

       $("#res").append(oddCount + " (n) <br>");
       oddCount++;
}
```

Check my fiddle to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/8/

Comment: Note to posters: Suggest looking at the fiddle code which is different from the snippet above, i.e., ignore the array mistake in the snippet as that doesn't appear in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your code show counting twice because you misses two '{' after "for loop" and "else". After I fix the code format, I don't see it counting twice anymore.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sub").bind("click", function() {
    $("#res").html("");

    var digits = $('#content').find("span").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    });

    var evenCount = 1;
    var oddCount = 1;

    for(var i =0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      if (digits[i] % 2 ==0) {
        oddCount = 1;

        $("#res").append(evenCount + " (l) <br>");
        evenCount++;
      } else {
        evenCount=1;

        $("#res").append(oddCount + " (n) <br>");
        oddCount++;
      }
    }      
  });
});
```

Second, they are many ways to implement that. Take a look at this jsfiddle code as an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/xk861vf9/11/

The concept is to print the counted number after even/odd number changes.  Then use for loop to print `<br>` x times (counted number - 1) so if counted number is 4, there will be 3 `<br>` tags followed.
We also have to check if current number is the last number in array and print the counted number or else the last counted number will be skipped.

Hope this help! :)

Ps. Sorry for my bad English, not my native language too.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this exactly what I needed!